# Pass object to child uiView using Angular's uiRouter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular application in which I'm creating a header to a page using uiRouter separate views:

Route config:

```
$stateProvider.state('content', {
    url: '/content/{idContent}',
    views: {
        'header@content': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/header.partial.html'
        },
        'mainContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/content/index.html'
        }
    }
});
```

Content template:

```
<section ng-controller="ContentController">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    {{Here I display the content}}
</section>
```

Header template:

```
<section ng-controller="ContentHeaderController">
    {{Here I render the header}}
</section>
```

The problem is, I need to access an object that is resolved in `ContentController` on the `ContentHeaderController`. I see that they don't share a parent scope:

> ContentController: 4
>
> ContentController's parent: 3
>
> ContentHeaderController: 6
>
> ContentHeaderController's parent: 5

How can I pass an object from the content view to it's header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of sharing data between controllers can be solved by using events (don't recommend it) and using services as models, which is a recommended way to do that because your data will be synchronized automatically and you will not be using soon to be deprecated API such as $broadcast.

The gist of this approach is to store data in service in an objects, not just as plain primitives on service intself, and then pass reference to this objects into controller where they are bound in template. Check this [blog post](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/model-pattern-for-angular-js-67494389d6f) about model pattern with code examples.